# Why is my navigation bar cutting off when I zoom in?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

For some reason, when I zoom in on the web page, the navigation bar condenses to a vertical bar (when there is not enough room for the horizontal bar to fit). I thought the "float:left" command would correct this from happening but I was wrong. How can I fix this?

```
.navbar
{
float:top;
width:100%;
height:30px;
display:inline-block;
}

li
{
float:left;
display:inline-block;
}

.nav 
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
}

a:link, a:visited
{
display:inline-block;
width:182.8px;
line-height:30px;
padding-top:12px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-bottom:12px;
padding-left:5px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
background-color:#006b00;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
float:left;
}

a:hover, a:active
{
background-color:#C0C0C0;
}

a:active
{
color:grey;
}

.nav_bar_text
{
font-size:17px;
}

.Mackin_text
{
font-size:17px;
vertical-align:text-center;
}
```

Here is my list code.

```
<div class="navbar">
<ul class="nav">
<li><a class="nav_bar_text" href="index.html">Home</li></a>
<li><a class="nav_bar_text" href="Resources">Resources</li></a>
<li><a class="nav_bar_text" href="Calendar">Calendar</li></a>
<li><a class="nav_bar_text" href="Year Plan">Year Plan</li></a>
<li><a class="nav_bar_text" href="Gallery">Gallery</li></a>
<li><a class="nav_bar_text" href="Videos">Videos</li></a>
<li><a class="Mackin_text" href="#Mackin Society">Mackin Society</li></a>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that your `navbar` and `nav` elements do not have a set width. `float` just tells elements to shrink to their content and behave *almost* like inline elements.

If you want your navbar to not condense you will need to give them a `min-width` so that when the screen shrinks, the navbar will at least be the necessary size to prevent the `li`s from going down to a new line.

Comment: Thank you so much! Virtual high five! I shall accept your answer in 3 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css:The width of li is in percentage (i put 14%)and background color property is set on li instead of a. The html code is the same.

Comment: If I set the background color property on the li element, it will not set the whole block to that color for some reason. The answer above solved my problem but the width of the li would also interfere with the block width (which I tinkered with for like 39 minutes to get it right). I appreciate the answer and wish I can 1+ you.